# How to parse partial dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How should I parse the following date with unknowns in momemnt.js?  I want a year back but empty date and month?

Here is what I trying to do:

var temp = moment("UN-UNK-2010",'DD-MMM-YYYY');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `moment` object is a lightweight wrapper on a JavaScript `Date`, with a few extra properties.  *Neither* can do what you are asking, because they both represent time as the number of milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1st 1970 UTC at midnight.

Your best bet is just to store the year as a number, instead of a `moment` or a `Date`.

Consider:

```js
var s = 'UN-UNK-2010';
var year = +s.split('-')[2];
```

Comment: And `luxon` author also states that such feature is out of scope: https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/179.